# Why there's no `Single#doOnTerminate` method in RxJava?

Tags: rx-java

RxJava's [Observable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#doOnTerminate(rx.functions.Action0)) has both `doOnTerminate` and `doAfterTerminate` methods.

The difference is that `doOnTerminate` is called *before* `onCompleted` or `onError` whereas `doAfterTerminate` is called *after*. Both methods seem useful.

[Single](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Single.html#doAfterTerminate(rx.functions.Action0)) however, has only `doAfterTerminate`.

Is there a reason why `Single` does not have `doOnTerminate` method?

Comment: check that doOnEvent() method.

Answer (score 4):

Just letting everyone know that `doOnTerminate` has been added for `Single` and `Maybe` in RxJava 2.2.7

See documentation: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Single.html#doOnTerminate-io.reactivex.functions.Action-

Comment: Thanks for informing. But as of version 2.2.19, it's still unstable.

Answer (score 2):

A single has 2 termination conditions

- a single item was emitted
- an error occured

In both cases, the termination is implicit in the operation. Given that it's only 2 methods, the extra operator might not have been seen as useful vs the effort for users to implement on their own.

Maybe you could write an email to the RxJava team and make a case for inclusion?

Comment: Before requesting new operators, see if existing combinations work for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you really needed the *just before `onComplete`* behavior, you can convert using `Single#toObservable`.

But, how I understand it: for an Observable, the term *before terminated* means *after all items are emitted, but before `onComplete`*. For Single, however, there is no such moment -- because emitting an item and completing is the same operation.

If there was a `doOnTerminate` operator, it would either mean something different (being run before the single item is emitted), or contradict the understanding of Single (emitting an item and completing is one action, so why should something be run in between) -- both of which would be kinda bad design.

Out of curiosity: what was your original case, that you couldn't make the call in `doAfterTerminate` or before launching the Single?